# "Updating" the RNG in Python

Tags: numpy, random

I have to iterate an operation over several sets of partially randomized copies of an initial array of 0 and 1.

I would like the copies to be different, of course, but also the sets.

For now I use this code (I omitted certain parts that should not interfere in the problem):

```
def randomizer(b) :
"""randomizes a fraction 'rate' (global variable) of b"""

    c = np.copy(b)
    num_elem = len(c)
    idx = np.random.choice(range(num_elem), int(num_elem*rate), replace=False)
    c[idx] = f(c[idx])
    return c

def randomizePatterns(pattern, randomizer) :
"""Return nbTrials partially randomized copies of the given input pattern"""
    outputs = np.tile(pattern,(nbTrials,1))   
    for line in xrange(nbTrials) :       
        outputs[line] = randomizer(outputs[line,:])   
    return outputs

def test(pattern,randomizer) :
    randomPatterns = randomizePatterns(pattern, randomizer)
    """test the dynamics of a neural network with a fixed but initially random 
    connection scheme, and returns a boolean corresponding to if 
    the original pattern that was randomized is retrieved from at least
     90% of the randomized patterns"""
    return boolean 

def metaTest(pattern):       
    successNumber = 0   

    for plop in xrange(10):                 
        if test(pattern, randomizer) :           
            successNumber += 1
    return successNumber
```

The other input to test is a random matrix of floats in [0,4] that I visualize and that has the expected behavior.
When I run metaTest, I always get either 0 or 10, never an intermediate value. 
Given the nature of test, I expect a result about 5. I get each result for approximately half of the inputs.

To be more precise, printing the random patterns after each incrementation of plop, I get the same thing ten times, and I would like that to change.

Comment: What do you get when you just call test ten times in a row and print it out? What is an example of your input pattern?

Comment: Rate is not defined in `randomizer`, should it read `b`? Several indentations don't work (comments, last if loop). Could you add what you use as inputs and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: `test` returns `bool`, which is nowhere assigned. Since you always see 0 or 10 for `successNumber`, knowing how `bool` got its value is probably key.

Comment: Sorry, I see I oversimplified so it becomes hard to read in the end... I'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: Doing 'test' manually ten times gives the same set of patterns (and thus the same answer) ten times.